# NSTimer can't start or run in a NSThread function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I want to use `NSTimer` to run a functions per 20 seconds,but I put the `NSTimer` in a `NSThread` function.the code is like this:

```
-(void)func1
{
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(func2)   
                         toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
-(void)func2
{
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self          
    selector:@selector(func3) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)func3
{
  //do something,but the function seems never be executed
}
```

So the problem is that the func3 is never executed by the `NSTimer` in func2.Some people say that the `NSTimer` only run in `main thread`.is it true??so Can't `NSTimer` start in a `NSThread` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like your thread is not doing anything. timers are scheduled to be check as part of a thread's run loop. If the thread is not running any code, then it will not go through it's run loop.

Think of it this way:

- Start Thread
- Begin Thread Run Loop
- `-func2`
- End Run Loop
- Sleep Thread

You have scheduled a timer on a thread that goes to sleep right after you setup the timer. No run loop; no timer fires.

---

**UPDATE**

My response answers the question but doesn't give a solution. What is the end effect you wish to achieve?

Comment: @Thomasso you mean the NSTimer can set and run in NSThread，not only in main thread?

Comment: If you had a long running thread, then you could set a timer on it. Long running thread would be things like a network thread which is downloading data in the background or a thread processing input from the camera or microphone.

Comment: It doesn't even go to sleep; the thread body is the `func2` method, which schedules the timer and then immediately returns, whereupon the thread exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timer to current thread's runloop by

```
(void)addTimer:(NSTimer*)aTimer forMode:(NSString*)mode
```

EDIT:

Helpful link for you: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW25

Comment: 1) The thread in question doesn't have a run loop set up.  2) The method OP uses automatically adds the timer to a run loop.